# Workaround for lack of cross domain AJAX support in Opera Mini

Tags: angularjs, ajax, cors, shim, opera-mini

According to  [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) and [opera.com](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/productspecs/),  Opera Mini doesn't support CORS. Is there a workaround? Can I make AJAX requests from/to a different domain or at least to a subdomain in AngularJS?

Comment: Have you tried `jsonp`? Although you ll have to be content with only `GET`  method.

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the following workarounds:

- `window.name` can be used to share data across domains. For example:

  ```
  window.name=window.StackExchange; window.location="http://www.example.com"; console.log(window.name);
  ```
- [DOM Level 3 Load and Save](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-LS)

> Any solution has its flaws but no one besides Opera allows a `data:URI`  which is not located on the same domain. Once `parseURI` can be executed combined with a `data:URI` the possibilities are endless - and it's very hard to determine the origin and content of the payload.
>
> Use the `data:URI` with a HTML document that loads the original page via XHR
>
> parseURI
>
> Parse an XML document from a location identified by a URI reference [IETF RFC 2396]. If the URI contains a fragment identifier (see section 4.1 in [IETF RFC 2396]), the behavior is not defined by this specification, future versions of this specification may define the behavior.

```
  function loadDataForVersion(core_version)
    {
    var features_doc = document.implementation.createLSParser(DOMImplementationLS.MODE_SYNCHRONOUS, "").parseURI("features."+core_version+".xml");
    var feature_nodes = features_doc.evaluate("//feature", features_doc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
    var feature_node;
    while (feature_node = feature_nodes.iterateNext())
      {
      addFeatureNode(features_doc, feature_node, core_version);
      }
    }
```

> Asynchronous `LSParser` objects are expected to also implement the events::EventTarget interface so that event listeners can be registered on asynchronous `LSParser` objects.
>
> Events supported by asynchronous `LSParser` objects are:
>
> load
>
> The `LSParser` finishes loading the document. See also the definition of the `LSLoadEvent` interface.
>
> progress
>
> The `LSParser` signals progress as data is parsed.
>
> This specification does not attempt to define exactly when progress events should be dispatched. That is intentionally left as implementation-dependent. Here is one example of how an application might dispatch progress events: Once the parser starts receiving data, a progress event is dispatched to indicate that the parsing starts. From there on, a progress event is dispatched for every 4096 bytes of data that is received and processed. This is only one example, though, and implementations can choose to dispatch progress events at any time while parsing, or not dispatch them at all.

- [CSSHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nbio/csshttprequest)

> A request is invoked using the CSSHttpRequest.get(url, callback) function:

```
CSSHttpRequest.get(
        "http://www.nb.io/hacks/csshttprequest/hello-world/",
        function(response) { alert(response); }
    );
```

> Data is encoded on the server into URI-encoded 2KB chunks and serialized into CSS @import rules with a modified `about:URI` scheme. The response is decoded and returned to the callback function as a string

**References**

- [Web Browser DOM Support](http://www.webdevout.net/browser-support-dom#dom3loadsave)
- [CSSHTTPRequest github repo](https://github.com/nbio/csshttprequest)
- [CSSHttpRequest: cross-domain Ajax using CSS for transport](http://ajaxian.com/archives/csshttprequest-cross-domain-ajax-using-css-for-transport)
- [Improve cross-domain communication with client-side solutions](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-crossdomaincomm/)
- [: Fun with XXE, Data Islands and parseURI: Index](http://maliciousmarkup.blogspot.com/2008/11/fun-with-xxe-data-islands-and-parseuri.html)
- [The sad state of DOM security (or how we all ruled Mario's challenge)](http://blog.kotowicz.net/2011/10/sad-state-of-dom-security-or-how-we-all.html)
- [Dev.Opera — Opera Mini and JavaScript](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/)
- [TVML Programming Guide: Implementing Search](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/ImplementingSearch.html)
- [Opera Mini: Web Content Authoring Guidelines](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-content-authoring-guidelines/)
- [Opera Mini Request Headers](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-request-headers/)